# how do I make a position in raphael js dynamic?

Tags: javascript, css, graph, raphael, graphael

I have designed something like this http://jsfiddle.net/suchitadoshi1987/dfNB8/ ,

Now i want to  dynamically put those three circles in different place. Its a graph basically and the circles inside the graph are the statistics. So can anyone help me out in positioning the circles dynamically?

thank you.

Comment: use a variable for the x and y coordinates of the circle() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [animate](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate) Raphael function with no animation time.
I forked your fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/UTsLJ/3/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response... so its like... the outer circle would be 100% and the inner circles would represent the percentages like 20% 10% 70%, so its like a graph. I m looking to make something like that on dynamic data. Hence I was looking for some way that would make this thing dynamic. So what should be the mathematical formula that I can put up so that it works for all the values?

Comment: In the example, I changed the circle positions, but you can also change the circle radius. `c1.animate({r:40})`. The number `40` can be calculated with Javascript : `c1.animate({r: percentage });`

Comment: cool! I had one more question./... How should I produce the hover effect so that it shows the data "on hover" of each inner circles?? Thanks!! :)

Comment: You can use mouseouver and mouseout event handlers like I did here :http://jsfiddle.net/UTsLJ/4/

Comment: THank you! but how do i add a tooltip? like 86.5 we are showing inside the circle, how do we show using a rectangular tooltip?